# Summer 18 Issues with lightning:textarea

Tags: lightning-aura-components, summer-18

Since a sandbox has been upgraded to Summer 18, I've been having a problem with a **lightning:textarea** showing undefined within it's box but only when I have used an apex controller to return the sobject fields.

Here is an example component in a Summer 18 org.

[image: Rendered Component]

And this is how it renders in a Spring 18 org.

[image]

I should note that all components are v42 in both orgs, not v43.

Here's an example Component:

```
<aura:component controller="TestLightningTextarea" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
  <aura:attribute type="Contact" name="contRecord" access="private"  />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
  <lightning:textarea label="Textarea" value="{!v.contRecord.Description}" />
  <lightning:input label="Input" value="{!v.contRecord.Description}" />
</aura:component>
```

Component Controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
  var getContactAct = component.get('c.getContact');
  getContactAct.setParams({'contactId' : component.get('v.recordId')});
  getContactAct.setCallback(this, function(response){
    component.set('v.contRecord', response.getReturnValue());
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue())));
  }, 'SUCCESS');
  $A.enqueueAction(getContactAct);
},
```

Apex Controller:

```
public with sharing class TestLightningTextarea {

  @AuraEnabled
  public static Contact getContact(Id contactId) {
    return [SELECT Id, Description FROM Contact WHERE Id = :contactId];
  }

}
```

[image: Console Log of the returned Contact record]

The controller queries the field, but it's not included in the payload to the lightning controller because it's empty.

Has anyone else seen this, and is there a way I can report this to Salesforce easily, given the customer I'm working with doesn't have Premier Support (thus  no development support)?

Comment: Do you work for a Partner? If you could mock this up in a pre-release org with the same results, you could report it with a case in the Partner Community. You could also try finding an appropriate group in the Success or Partner community that would tag someone appropriately technical on the Lightning team.

Comment: I've replicated it in a prerelease org, so i'll try the partner portal support route. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed with a recent Summer 18 patch, no mention of it anywhere though.